# Lua local require of modules in different files

Tags: lua

I learned that `require` only loads a file once it's loaded (in `package.loaded`). However I see the following behavior and would like to get some pointers on what is happening.

Say I have a file `lib/q.lua`:

```
local q = {}

local function dep()
  return 1;
end

q.dep = dep;
return q;
```

Another file `lib/p.lua`:

```
local q = require('./lib/q');
local p = {}
local function result()
  return q;
end
p.result = result;
return p;
```

Another file `main.lua`:

```
local p = require('./lib/p');
local q = require('./lib/q');
local assert = require('luassert');

local result = p.result();
print(result);
print(package.loaded['./lib/q']);
print(q);
assert.is_equal(q, result);
```

The value of `package.loaded['./lib/q']` is the same as `result`. However its value is different from the `local q` in `main.lua`. I expected them to be the same. Is there documentation on this or I'm missing something.

New to Lua. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is the problem solved after fixing the typo in your question?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It didn't solve my problem. I am going to make an edit to specify the paths properly.

Comment: Actually, after fixing the paths to ./lib/q and ./lib/q instead of lib/p and lib/q, my problem is solved. The keypoint is that in all requires, they should use the same path (consistently ./lib/p or lib/p for example). Thanks again. It's a user problem.

Comment: BTW, Lua automatically converts dots to slashes and removes all first slashes: `./lib/q` -> `//lib/q` -> `lib/q`.  This actually means that you are not able to ask Lua to go to the current directory `.` or the parent directory `..` or root of the file system directory `/`.

Comment: I see. TIL. Thank you!